# Debuging website in native android browser run in AVD(android studio)

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, mobile-devices

I have to debug some problems on website I recently created that occur only in native android browser on some tablets. I don't have access to physical device so I decided to to install Android Studio and created tablet AVD(android virtual device). Process run smoothly and now I can open native browser in virtual device and check my website.

I can see the same errors as those reported on tablets(that's great) but I cannot figure out how to run any kind of devtools in native browser. Even access to console output would be enough.

I'm running android studio on Ubuntu 18.x LTS, but I guess my question is not platform specific.

I would prefer any solution that can be run on virtual device(like some additional app that acts as debugger), even if it would give me only console output, over more sophisticated ones that require more complicated configuration.

But, honestly, I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the Chrome debug bridge; accessible through `chrome://inspect` on the desktop browser... connected devices will show up there, as long as USB debugging is enabled; that should work with an emulator, as well.

Comment: I see, I thought i cannot use usb debugging, but android studio set everything up for me. Thank you.

Comment: @agsigma it's enabled for emulator images by default - because it is their main purpose (they also show up in `adb` as "connected devices").